# Find the difference between pyMongo result and a set of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pandas, pymongo

How can you find the difference between the results of a `pyMongo` query and a list of `pandas` DataFrame based on the comparison of 1 common field `timestamp`?

**Normal Comparison between lists**

```
from sets import Set

x = ["1385754660", "1385754661", "1385754662"]
y = ["1385754662", "1385754663"]

toAdd = set(x) - set(y)
toRemove = set(y) - set(x)

print toAdd
print toRemove
```

**Comparison between Pandas DataFrames and pyMongo result**

```
x1 = pd.DataFrame(['Jack', 1385754660], index={'name','timestamp'})
x2 = pd.DataFrame(['Tomm', 1385754661], index={'name','timestamp'})
x3 = pd.DataFrame(['Neil', 1385754662], index={'name','timestamp'})
x = [x1,x2,x3]

y = db.users.find().limit(2)

# Code to find differences (toAdd and toRemove)
```

**Question:** How do we compare the timestamps in `x` with the timestamps in `y` and determine the results `toAdd` and `toRemove`?

`toAdd` and `toRemove` will then be used to insert and remove documents from the mongodb database. In `toAdd` we will have a list of DataFrames for inserting into the database. In `toRemove` we will have a list of the `_id` of the documents that should be removed from the database.